# An alternative to MYSQL SET datatype

Tags: php, mysql

i have a column where i want to store user's subscription (i.e what they have subscribed to on my subscription platform) i tried using SET datatype, but it has a Limit of 64 values, what users can subscribe to could rise beyond 64 and there will be a problem if a user subscribe above 64 items.

i also tried having another table that maps the user_id to the item_id upon subscription, but it could be a drawback when the database begins to grow.

Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: The drawback of SET is that you got to issue an ALTER statement to get another SET value. Because of that is SET not a suitable solution for the intended use. The second table is a suitable one without any drawback as @spencer7593 said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normative approach for repeating attributes is a second table.

It's not at all clear why you think the separate table will be a drawback "when the database begins to grow".

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** If i have a second table that has up to 10,000 values of user's subscription and i am looking for a user's only one subscription it will take longer time to query. i am thinking of storing the user's subscription as an object in the users tables like a string object which i ll just query

**A:** No, a query of the second table won't take longer, if the second table has suitable indexes.

The query will actually be **faster**.

**`-- sample table`**

```
CREATE TABLE user_subscription 
( user_id         INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK, FK to user.id'
, subscription_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK'
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id,subscription_id)
, UNIQUE KEY user_subscription_UX1 (subscription_id,user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

**`-- populate`**

```
INSERT INTO user_subscription
SELECT s.d*10000 + u.d*1000 + h.d*100 + t.d*10 + o.d + 1 AS user_id, 1
  FROM digit s
  JOIN digit u
  JOIN digit h
  JOIN digit t
  JOIN digit o
 ORDER BY s.d, u.d, h.d, t.d, o.d ;
INSERT INTO user_subscription
SELECT s.user_id, s.subscription_id + 1
  FROM user_subscription s
 WHERE s.subscription_id = 1 ;      
INSERT INTO user_subscription
SELECT s.user_id, s.subscription_id + 2
  FROM user_subscription s
 WHERE s.subscription_id <= 2 ;      
INSERT INTO user_subscription
SELECT s.user_id, s.subscription_id + 4
  FROM user_subscription s
 WHERE s.subscription_id <= 4 ;
```

**`-- total rows`**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM user_subscription
COUNT(1)  
----------
    800000
```

**`-- sample query 1`**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT t.*
  FROM user_subscription t
 WHERE t.user_id = 878

id select_type table  type   possible_keys key     key_len ref      rows Extra        
-- ----------- ------ ------ ------------- ------- ------- -----  ------ -----------
 1 SIMPLE      t      ref    PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       const       8 Using index
```

**-- example query 2**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT t.*
  FROM user_subscription t
 WHERE t.subscription_id = 4

id select_type table  type possible_keys         key                   key_len ref      rows Extra
-- ----------- ------ ---- --------------------- --------------------- ------- -----  ------  -------------
1 SIMPLE       t      ref  user_subscription_UX1 user_subscription_UX1 4       const  184412  Using index
```

---

Compare that to storing the "subscriptions" of a user as a list in a `VARCHAR` column (the same representation in and out of the database as used for a `SET` datatype. And writing a query to identify users that have a particular subscription, e.g.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT u.user_id
  FROM users u
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(4,u.subscriptions)
```

You'll find that MySQL will need to inspect *every* row in the `users` table to see if the criteria is met.

Comment: If i have a second table that has up to 10,000 values of user's subscription and i am looking for a user's only one subscription it   will take longer time to query. i am thinking of storing the user's subscription as an object in the users tables like a string object which i ll just query from but dont know how that will work out

Comment: @Tobby: It could take a "longer time to query" of there isn't a suitable index defined on the table; with suitable indexes available, getting the users subscribed to something will be very quick; if these  are stored as part of a VARCHAR within each user row, the database will be forced to look at every flipping row in the table, to look at each and every user, to find out if that user is subscribed to something. Also, operations like adding a subscription to a user, and removing a particular subscription from all users, are going to require more resources.